# How to debug assembly with KDBG

Tags: assembly, gdb, gnu-assembler, kdbg

I am trying to debug some assembly with kdbg on ubuntu.  I can step through the program instruct by instruction however I can not find a way to see the assembly code while I do this.  I know you can see the machine code in gdb (I really don't want to debug through a terminal).  Is there a way to see the machine code?

Comment: And disassemble command does not work?